# Serious issues with speed in 22.04.3

Tags: networking, 22.04, vpn, raid, performance

I have read many posts and tried a few basic things to resolve this issue, but before I take more ambitious actions, I thought I would seek help.

I am running 22.04.3; I like to stick with LTS releases for all the normal reasons that some people do that. I have a quite-old 2011 Dell desktop with "eight-core" i7 processor. I have a Intel "hardware" RAID 1 as the boot drive.

Up until recently, everything was fine and dandy. About a week ago, the speed of this computer ground almost completely to a halt. This was most noticeable while running Firefox browser. However, since then I am finding that I can barely do anything at all. For example, right now I have been waiting 1/2 hour for the computer to boot (normally takes perhaps 1 minute). It does gradually make progress, but it really really takes forever to do anything at all. While it is loading programs, if I look at the resource monitor, I notice that either the resource monitor is not working, or if it is working, there is no strain on the computer---the processor load is minimal, not much RAM is being used, and the network is more-or-less quiet. In other words, there is nothing happening, and therefore the loading of any program is VERY SLOW.

The situation describing is was coincident with my trying to solve a VPN issue in which I wasn't able to access outside websites while connected to VPN on the local machine. However, I am not really claiming that these are related. It seems coincidental to me. I could not find a way to solve the VPN issue without resorting to the current method with is to use netplan (my understanding). There was nothing in the netplan directory from my upgrade to 22.04, so I had to do it manually, using the process described in several articles on the subject. Ultimately I could not get this to work, but I think I just haven't gotten the settings right. I am connecting to PAN Global Protect.

At this point, I have made sure to completely upgrade all packages. This ended up being a little bit of a process; for some reason many packages were being held. (possibly the cause of or maybe a symptom of whatever issue I'm having?). I was able to get everything updated by manually apt-get of each one sequentially and repeatedly doing apt autoremove. I believe I am now fully updated.

However, things are still really slow. I tried turning iommu off, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Next I will try turning off thermald.

Side comment is that my network connections are wrecked as of most-recent reboot.

I have never had issues this bad with Ubuntu. 22.04 is very disappointing.

Thanks

Sean

EDIT 1: Additional RAID info.
No prior issues with the raid except that when I upgraded to 22.04 originally (last year), the RAID did not work at all, and the computer would therefore not even boot. I fixed that (can't recall what exactly but I used a USB bootable ubuntu drive and I think I just had to repair the name of the drive it was booting to).

However, a couple of days ago (after speed issues had been occurring for several days already), when the computer was booting it got stuck on the Dell + Bios screen. I tried to let it to its business but it ran for many minutes at full whack. Finally I had to power cycle it, after which it did boot as normal, but now there is a SMART event detected, presumably over-temp for one of the RAID drives. I have never noticed any issues with either drive before on that screen. I assumed that the failed boot-up lock-up caused an overtemp. May also be coincidence. Here is the `lshw` info:

```
   *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             logical name: scsi2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: raid msi pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:27 ioport:4090(size=8) ioport:4080(size=4) ioport:4070(size=8) ioport:4060(size=4) ioport:4020(size=32) memory:e1540000-e15407ff
           *-disk:0
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD10EALX-759
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 1H19
                serial: WD-WCATR8410859
                size: 931GiB (1TB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=0000d8c4
              *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 59db399e-f827-4109-9d4a-80c3a06fe246
                   size: 923GiB
                   capacity: 923GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-09-06 10:54:40 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-07-21 12:35:23 mounted=2023-09-22 12:06:53 state=clean
              *-volume:1 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   size: 8147MiB
                   capacity: 8147MiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume UNCLAIMED
                      description: Linux swap volume
                      physical id: 5
                      version: 1
                      serial: 29cea475-fa94-4a3d-9227-e88017ececcb
                      size: 8147MiB
                      capacity: 8147MiB
                      capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                      configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
           *-disk:1
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD10EALX-759
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                version: 1H19
                serial: WD-WCATR8422235
                size: 931GiB (1TB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=0000d8c4
              *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 59db399e-f827-4109-9d4a-80c3a06fe246
                   size: 923GiB
                   capacity: 923GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-09-06 10:54:40 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-07-21 12:35:23 mounted=2023-09-22 12:06:53 state=clean
              *-volume:1 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                   size: 8147MiB
                   capacity: 8147MiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume UNCLAIMED
                      description: Linux swap volume
                      physical id: 5
                      version: 1
                      serial: 29cea475-fa94-4a3d-9227-e88017ececcb
                      size: 8147MiB
                      capacity: 8147MiB
                      capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                      configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
```

EDIT 2: RAID errors from smartctl -a

```
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD10EALX-759BA1
Serial Number:    WD-WCATR8410859
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2b0cffb90
Firmware Version: 19.01H19
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Sep 22 16:16:02 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (15960) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 185) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   199   199   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       8672
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   176   167   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4191
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2636
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   069   069   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 1043
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   050   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       37073
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2634
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       210
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2425
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       410
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       103
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       85
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   193   193   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1492
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   054   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       33972
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       35557148779
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       28469971659
```

output from /dev/sdb is the same other than that it passes, but it does have similar pre-fail and old_age marks. Nothing that says "failing now."

Comment: What kind of drives do you have? Are some of them failing? Intel 'raid' is not hardware raid, it's just a marketing term for software raid...

Comment: I don't think you are right about that. I checked my recollection to make sure. I appended what lshw gives me into my original question. "SATA RAID bus controller" seems pretty unambiguous. I am open to learning, though, so please explain if I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: It's fakeraid. But what drives do you have, and what is the smart status of the drives?

Comment: Ok I am now using smartctl and I am seeing the errors. The outputs of smartctl are pretty long, but I can append those, too. Is the fix for this to replace both drives? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.` not a fun read...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a drive that's failing. It spends time reallocating sectors instead of returning read data. You need to replace the disk that says it's failing.

The `Old_age` and `Pre_fail` is merely the type of indicator, and doesn't indicate a problem. The counters increasing and `FAILING_NOW` indicates that this measurement indicates failure of the drive.

As a sidenote, you'll probably get better performance and reliability by going for a single SSD. A simple SATA SSD that will blow your spinning disks out of the water can be had for 60USD nowadays. It will probably be the single biggest performance improvement for such old hardware you can have.

Comment: Drive failures are more likely to show up after a distribution upgrade because the upgrade involves a large amount of writing to the disk, often to sectors that were previously rarely or never written to. A drive might have been sputtering along with a tolerable amount of errors (tolerable in the sense of your system having a usable speed) but grind to a halt after an upgrade for these reasons. It shows up in the browser bc of the use of disk for caching. It's always best to be proactive and replace the drive earlier; by the time things get this bad there is risk of data loss.

Comment: I appreciate your help and your suggestions, vidarlo and cazort. After considering my options I am likely to let this computer go and to start over with fresh hardware and a fresh install of 22.04. I'd have liked to fix it, but I have been maintaining it since 2012 or so, and I think it's time. I would hate to put more time into it just to have a motherboard, etc. fail.